# What do I miss with ILogger<T> via Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, ilogger

I have the following sample code:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Playground.Startup))]

namespace Playground
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole());
            builder.Services.AddLogging(logging => logging.AddDebug());
            builder.Services.AddLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug));
        }
    }
    
    public class InProcSO
    {
        private readonly ILogger<InProcSO> _logger;

        public InProcSO(ILogger<InProcSO> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(InProcSO))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("works not");
            logger.LogInformation("works");

            return new OkObjectResult("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

The injected logger in the constructor seems not to do what I would expect. It does not log to console.

So I added an additional ILogger parameter in the Run method, and that one does deliver the output. So what do I miss in my code or do not understand correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Log levels by any chance? Are you able to inspect the two loggers in the debugger?

Comment: Move the SetMinimumLevel before AddConsole

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your reply: the two look identical to me, both have added the console and debug logger. I also tried different log levels, outcome is the same. Maybe I should add I am using .net 6 core and 6.0 packages

Comment: @XavierJ I tried, makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit baffled, but it seems I had to add the log level to my host.json file. That solved the issue. But still not explains the different behavior for me...
´

```
    {
        "version": "2.0",
        "logging": {
            "logLevel": {
                "default": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
```